# FluentAssertions - complete tutorial for creating custom assertions

Tags: fluent-assertions

Has anybody seen a complete tutorial for creating custom assertion classes with FluentAssertions?
Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I maintain a couple of extension packages for Fluent Assertions, so feel free to take a look at our code to see how we do it:

- [FluentAssertions.Mvc](https://github.com/CaseyBurns/FluentAssertions.MVC)
- [FluentAssertions.Ioc.Ninjet](https://github.com/kevinkuszyk/FluentAssertions.Ioc.Ninject)

I also recently contributed the assembly reference assertions to the core, so have a look at this [pull request](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions/pull/106).  Also have a look at the FA source to see how they implement similar assertions (that's where we started).

The top line is you'll need a class to hold your assertions and an extension method to hook it in.